# Помогите заставить квадратик не двигаться по оси y

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveInput;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * moveInput, ???);
    }
}
```

Подскажите что указать в месте, которое обозначено знаками "???".
При указании 0f квадрат падает вниз.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY.html

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете либо сделать ваш Rigidbody [Kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyType2D.html), но тогда он перестанет быть динамичным, либо поставить одно из значения [Constraints](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html), а именно [FreezePositionY](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY.html), на true.

Это можно сделать в инспекторе или коде:

```
rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
```

Извращенный способ (не делайте так!): прикладываем к телу силу, равную его силе тяжести и оно не падает, вуаля:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * moveInput, rb.mass * Physics2D.gravity));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

На место `???` поставь `rb.velocity.y`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто помог. Как оказалось, для решения проблемы надо было поставить компоненте Rigidbody2D в поле гравитации 0. а на ??? вписать либо 0 либо rb.velocity.y